# Export to SHP with ArcPy with query

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, export, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile with table with area code (field `areacode`).

How can I export with ArcPy each unique area code so I get a SHP file for each one?

It takes too long to select the layer and query each area code and then export manually to SHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to export features in a shapefile to new shapefiles.  The `SHAPE@` token allows you to access individual feature geometry.  The [Feature Class To Feature Class (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) tool does the conversion to shapefile.  You can also specify a subset of features you would like to export by specifying a query

```
query = """"areacode" > 2"""
```

---

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\path\to\your\shapefile'
outpath = r'C:\out\path'

query = """"areacode" > 2"""

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["SHAPE@", "areacode"], query) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Note* using the "areacode" to name the output
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (row[0], outpath, row[1])
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me But when I search for areacode I it is ok but when I use it on postalcode I get error 

areacode is Long and postalcode is String


raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. An invalid SQL statement was used. An invalid SQL statement was used. Failed to execute

Comment: @Sigster If you are querying a new field, you should add it to the field list.  For example: ["SHAPE@", "areacode", "postalcode"].  You can then reference the new postalcode field by calling `row[2]`.

Comment: No this is field I already have in the shp file
with your sample it was in endless loop so I query like this

with the postalcode it work well and no problem with but if I use this on areacode I get error
area_code is Type String

import arcpy  
fc = "C:\\Samples\\shipefile.shp"  
where = """"postalcode" = 1100"""  
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, "C:\\Samples\\ut", "1100_street.shp", where) 

the error if I query area_code what is TypeString

raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. An invalid SQL statement was used. An invalid SQL

Comment: Fix this where = '"postalcode" = \'8000\'' Regards
Sigster