# Debugging code to export .shp that gives invalid SQL statement was used?

Tags: arcpy, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile composed of a number of polygons. The shapefile has table column entitled as name (field: NAME).

How can I export with ArcPy each polygon so I get a shapefile for each one and it's name (ex: name.shp) corresponds with the ones in the table column?

I've attempted to use the following code:

```
import arcpy
shp = "c:/temp/folder/shapefile.shp"
TargetFolder = "c:/temp/folder"
query = """"NAME" > 2"""
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["NAME","SHAPE@"], query) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row[0], TargetFolder, row[1])
```

I get the error code: An invalid SQL statement was used.

I used code from [Export to SHP with ArcPy with query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114005/export-to-shp-with-arcpy-with-query) as the basis for mine.

Comment: NAME > 2 is a numeric operator which you're trying to implement on a string field, this is why it's complaining. What is it that you think this query is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some working code that I have modified (simplified) to suit your purpose, the original is more generic but may be confusing:

```
import os, sys, arcpy

InShp     = "c:/temp/folder/shapefile.shp" # from your values
OutFolder = "c:/temp/folder"
Field     = "NAME"

UValues = [] # an empty list, then recurse and add each unique value
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InShp,Field,Field + " Is not null") as sCur:
    for sRow in sCur:
        if sRow[0] not in UValues:
            UValues.append(sRow[0])

for ThisValue in UValues: # loop through the values
    ShpName = "{}\\{}.shp".format(OutFolder,ThisValue) # generate the shapefile name from the 'name' field value

    arcpy.AddMessage("Exporting {} to {}".format(ThisValue,ShpName)) # not necessary but nice to have
    arcpy.Select_analysis(InShp,ShpName,"{} = '{}'".format(Field,ThisValue))
```

First, using a search cursor get all the unique values for 'Name' field (note: case sensitive, which can cause problems later), then iterate the unique values and use [select](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000005000000) to export each using a where clause to a shapefile - named after the value in the name so make sure there are valid shapefile names (don't use non alphanumeric characters in your names).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that:

```
query = '"NAME"> ' + str(2)
```

does not work then, like @Michael Stimson said, it's probably an issue of NAME being a text field. Maybe try basing it on OID:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ['OID@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        feature_number = row[0]
        if feature_number > 2:
            shp_out = 'OutName_' + str(feature_number) + '.shp'
            arcpy.SplitByAttributes_analysis(shp_out, TargetFolder, ['NAME'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I still receive the same error code: "An invalid SQL statement was used."

Comment: Note that the SplitByAttributes_analysis tool is new at 10.5, users of 10.4 and previous versions don't have access to this tool. I thought I'd mention it here before someone tries to utilize this code and gets *object has no property* errors that are hard to diagnose.